# Python code for Discord Bot using discord.py getting "using variable before assignment" error

Tags: python, discord.py

I am new to both Python and Stack Exchange.  When using this code, I receive the error, "Using variable 'status' before assignment [30,96]."  It says that the variable status is unassigned in the await command in the loop, even though I assigned it above.  If anyone could solve this, I would appreciate it.  If any other info is needed, just ask and I can reply with it.  Thanks.

```
import requests
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext import tasks
from itertools import cycle

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
status = cycle(['Starting.', 'Starting..'])

serverOnePlayerCount = 0
serverTwoPlayerCount = 0
serverOneOnline = 'Offline'
serverTwoOnline = 'Offline'

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('Bot is ready.')



@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')



@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(name=next(status), type=3))

    r1 = requests.get('https://api.minehut.com/server/5f0de3303c826f0051e583b1/')
    json_data_1 = r1.json()

    serverOneOnline = str(json_data_1["server"]["online"])
    serverOnePlayerCount = str(json_data_1["server"]["playerCount"])

    serverOneStatusMessage = 'Minecraft ----- Server 1 is {} ({}/10 players)'.format(serverOneOnline, serverOnePlayerCount)



    r2 = requests.get('https://api.minehut.com/server/5f8242b2d74dc1006100293b/')
    json_data_2 = r2.json()

    serverTwoOnline = str(json_data_2["server"]["online"])
    serverTwoPlayerCount = str(json_data_2["server"]["playerCount"])

    serverTwoStatusMessage = 'Minecraft ----- Server 2 is {} ({}/10 players)'.format(serverTwoOnline, serverTwoPlayerCount)
    

    
    status = cycle([serverOneStatusMessage, serverTwoStatusMessage])
    

    
client.run('token')
```

Comment: Inside `change_status()`, `status` is a local variable (due to the presence of an assignment to that name in the function), completely unrelated to the global variable of the same name.  You would need a `global status` declaration in that function to override Python's determination that it's a local variable.

Comment: New to Python? Just don't start on discord.py. If you're new, I recommend smaller projects than a bot. Please. I'm honestly tired from telling people this.

Comment: @Makonede, please don’t use comments like this, your comment has not provided anything towards the post. If you are going to leave a comment like that, why don’t you leave some references or guides you could recommend to help people.